# I need to drill but have detected metal approx 3" x 3". Not pipes, not wires. Can I drill?

Tags: conduit

I cannot vary the location of a hole I need to drill in a masonry wall, but I have detected metal - about 3 x 3".  This spot of metal is completely isolated ie does not track in a line to plugs, switches etc and is definitely not pipes.  i am in a basement so nothing comes up from underneath.  it is an internal wall and this 'patch' is also detectable from the other side of the wall where there is also no plug sockets etc.  what is it likely to be and can I drill safely?

Comment: If you don’t know what it is how can you say it is not something? Main feeders for conduit would not go to a plug or receptacle. A sewer vent line may also be 3” I would not want to drill into that especially since cast is a common plumbing material on my side of the pond for sewer in older homes and you take a chance of cracking it then you are really up S4!t creek without a paddle.

Comment: `can I drill safely?` ... how can you even think to ask that? ... you can only ask that when you determine exactly what is in the wall

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is No, you can't drill.

Drilling into masonry and hitting something unexpected can be dangerous and expensive.  That's why you scanned first, which was wise.  (No idea what you used to scan...)  Your scan found something, but you don't have enough information to know what with any confidence.  It could be nothing more than a scrap of metal that fell in the mix when the concrete was poured, it could be buried treasure, it could be something else that shocks, floods, or explodes.  Drilling into it is not the way to find out what it is.

There are other difficulties drilling through metal embedded in masonry but that's another matter.

Comment: sometimes, a small metal plate, about 3x3" is emplaced Over wires or gas pipe where they pass through studs.  the plate is there to 'remind' you not to drill into the wires/gas pipe etc...